# Swift: Edit value of Label when pressing a button

Tags: ios, swift, button, label

I'm trying to learn Swift and I'm playing around with the basics of variables. I made an app where when you press a button, the value of a label changes, and while the button that adds 1 works, the one that subtracts one doesn't. If I change the first button (plusone) to subtract one, then it works, so I assume it is something to do with how the code is parsed? Would you be kind enough to explain how this works? Thanks in advance.

The code is here:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var value = 0
    @IBOutlet var number: UILabel!

    @IBAction func plusone(_ sender: Any) {
        value = value+1
        number.text = "\(value)"
    }

    @IBAction func plustwo(_ sender: Any) {
        value = value-1
        number.text = "\(value)"
    }

}
```

And the app looks like this if that matters:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcN0F.jpg)

The second button is named 'plustwo' because I haven't figured out where else I need to rename it, if I just rename it here the app displays a blank screen and nothing else.

Comment: Did you connect the 2 btns the same way ???

Comment: Yes, I'm really confused. If I get them both to do negative or positive operations (so plusone does value +1 and plustwo does value +2) they both work. Not if one is positive while the other is negative though.

Comment: Control click in your buttons in IB and check their connections.  You might have one of your buttons connected to both functions.

Comment: I changed plustwo to -2 and it works as intended.
Pressing Add One adds one and pressing Substract One substracts one. I am not sure why..

Comment: @vacawama no each of the buttons works as intended, see my comment above, I think the problem is with how variables work

Comment: Yeah, you must have your Subtract One button wired to both `plusone` and `plustwo`.  So adding 1 and subtracting 2 ends up subtracting one.

Comment: Add `print("in plusone")` to `plusone` and add `print("in plustwo")` to `plustwo` and then watch the console when you press the buttons.

Comment: You are right @vacawama, that solved the problem sorry I was being an idiot. Can you post this as an answer so I can mark the question as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

> I changed plustwo to -2 and it works as intended. Pressing Add One
>   adds one and pressing Substract One substracts one. I am not sure why.

The behavior you describe tells me that you have your *Subtract One* button wired to both the `plusone` and `plustwo` functions.  You can check this by <kbd>control</kbd>-clicking on your button in *Interface Builder* and checking the connections.  If you see *TouchUpInside* wired to two functions, remove one by clicking on the `x` to delete the connection.

Another way you can verify the behavior is to add logging `print` statements to your functions such as `print("in plusone")` and `print("in plustwo")`.  When you press *Subtract One*, if you see both messages in the console then you know you have your button connected to both `@IBAction`s.

**How did this happen?** This frequently happens when you copy a button in *Interface Builder* that already has a connection to an `@IBAction`.  Connecting it to a new `@IBAction` doesn't replace the first one, it just connects to both of them and calls both when the button is pressed.

> The second button is named 'plustwo' because I haven't figured out
>   where else I need to rename it, if I just rename it here the app
>   displays a blank screen and nothing else.

To rename the function, you need to change the name of the function *and* remove and reconnect the connection in *Interface Builder*.  As described above, <kbd>control</kbd>-click on the button in *Interface Builder* and remove the connection to the old function name, then connect the button to the new function.